# Using For Iterator in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, iterator

I'm trying to build a rather easy model but somehow couldn't find a solution to one problem:
I work with a main model and a submodel which contains the iterator "for". I want to buffer a feature class ("building") with different distances. I added %value% to the output name so that the outputs are not overwritten. Afterwards I would like to use one of the outputs in the main model in a "union". But I have no idea how to get it as an input value. I thought I could open the tool and write down the path of the buffered feature class I want to use. But it's not working. I guess it's because it doesn't exists at that moment but I thought it'll work since it's created during the process of the model.

Is there any easy solution?

[image]

Comment: You should probably change %value% to %Value%

Comment: I think to help clarify, when you say "...I would like to use one of the outputs in the main model in a "union"..." which buffered building are you talking about, anyone will do or a specific one? Because I would imagine it will always be the last buffer that you'll end up referencing?

Comment: changing %value% to %Value% doesn't change anything.

I need a specific one. But it's not working at all. When I use the output of the submodel as the input for union it stops and says "building%value% doesn't exist and when I use the path and "building100" - which I get as an output - as an input, the tool just stops before the union (model stays white)